# How i can call with postman a pod?

Tags: url, kubernetes

I would call my po with postman, but i don't such the url.
i run my pod with this yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongo-db
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: mongodb-pod
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/mongodb
  containers:
  - image: bitnami/mongodb:latest
    name: mongodb
    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 0):

forexample your template name is test.yml
you should run

`kubectl create -f test.yml --v=8`

and you can see your request body and see every thing and put them in postman and enjoy it.